# Show highest value untop of a bars when dataset is stacked (chartjs)

Tags: chart.js

I have this code:

```
 animation: {
     duration: 500,

     onComplete: function() {                                                                       
         var ctx = this.chart.ctx;

         var chart = this;

         ctx.textAlign = "center";

         ctx.textBaseline = "middle";

         var datasets = this.config.data.datasets;

         ctx.font = "15px QuickSand";

         datasets.forEach(function (dataset, i) {
             switch ( chart.getDatasetMeta(i).type ) {
                 case "bar":
                     ctx.fillStyle = "#303030";

                     chart.getDatasetMeta(i).data.forEach(function (p, j) 
                     {
                         ctx.fillText(datasets[i].data[j], p._model.x, p._model.y - 10);
                     });
                 break;
             }
         });
     }                                                               
 }
```

And these datasets:

```
datasets: [
    {
        backgroundColor: '#f87979',
        data: [6500, 5500]},
    {
        backgroundColor: '#f8f8ee', 
        data: [4800, 5600]
    }
]
```

The dataset is set to be stacked using.

```
scales: {
    xAxes: [{
        barThickness: 25,
            stacked: true,
            ticks: {
               beginAtZero: true,
               padding: 0,
               fontSize: 13
            }
    }],
    yAxes: [{
        stacked: true,
        display: false
    }]
},
```

What the above code does is placing the values over the bars. My problem is that i want to show the highest value from each dataset at above each bar.
And not all the values from each point.

Can you guys help me with this? I have been trying to do this for like a  1 day now.

To clearify instead of this:

[Image with all values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q75Vz.png)

I want this:
[Image with wanted values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/boKqf.png)

Answer (score 1):

check out this jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/umsbywLg/2/

essentially I calculated the max value and then drew that on top on the stacked bars:

```
onComplete: function() {                                                                       
               var ctx = this.chart.ctx;
               var chart = this;
               ctx.textAlign = "center";
               ctx.textBaseline = "middle";

               var datasets = this.config.data.datasets;

               ctx.font = "15px QuickSand"; 
               ctx.fillStyle = "#303030";

               datasets.forEach(function (dataset, i) {
                    var maxValue = 0;
                    chart.getDatasetMeta(i).data.forEach(function (p, j) {
                        if(maxValue < datasets[j].data[i]) {
                            maxValue = datasets[j].data[i];
                        }
                    });

                    ctx.fillText(maxValue, datasets[i]._meta[0].data[i]._view.x, 20);        
               });
           }
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!

Comment: On second though this is not want i wanted. Because it's the total value across all the datasets.. I want it to set the total value from each dataset untop. Not the total value across all datasets.

Comment: I'm not too sure what you mean, could you update your two images above, to show what you desire using the first image. It's confusing having a different graph for the second image. I can then help you out!